# PHP - Sending sql command as a string thru two php files

Tags: php, sql, include

EDIT: This is a original code, that is working ok. sorry for formating.

```
<?php

$target = "images/"; 
    if(!is_dir($target)) mkdir($target); $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

$uvod = $_POST['uvod']; $text = $_POST['text']; $nadpis = $_POST['nadpis']; $datum = date("Y-m-d");

if (isset($_POST['zobrazeno'])) {

    $zobrazeno = 1; }  else  {

   $zobrazeno = 0; }

$fname=($_FILES['photo']['name']); $funiquename = uniqid() . $fname; $tmpName  = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']; $fileSize = $_FILES['photo']['size']; $fileType = $_FILES['photo']['type'];



$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r'); $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName)); $content = addslashes($content); fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){ $fname = addslashes($fname);}

require_once 'db_config.php'; $db_server=mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);

if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL" .mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database,$db_server) or die("Unable to connect to database" .mysql_error()); 


$sql = "INSERT INTO `aktuality` (`nadpis`, `uvod`, `text`, `datum`, `zobrazeno`, `obr_nazev`, `obr_pripona`, `obr_velikost`, `obr_data`) VALUES ('$nadpis', '$uvod', '$text', '$datum', '$zobrazeno', '$funiquename','$fileType','$fileSize','$content')"; 
    mysql_query($sql);


 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) { 

echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
       }    else { 

 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
    } 
     ?>
```

Im a php beginner.
I have a problem with sending sql command as a string thru two php files.

This php file should call function sql_string() in sql.php, but there is nothing happens.

```
<?php
    ------some code here-------
    include 'sql.php';
    mysql_query(sql_string1());
    ------some code here------
 ?>
```

sql.php

```
<?php
  function sql_string1()
  {
    $sql ="INSERT INTO `aktuality` (`nadpis`, `uvod`, `text`, `datum`, `zobrazeno`, `obr_nazev`, `obr_pripona`, `obr_velikost`, `obr_data`) VALUES ('$nadpis', '$uvod', '$text', '$datum', '$zobrazeno', '$funiquename','$fileType','$fileSize','$content')";
    return $sql;
  }
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where are parameters for your function?

Comment: Replace `mysql_query(sql_string1());` with `echo sql_string1();`. I'm pretty sure you get a response.

Comment: By "nothing happens" do you mean it doesn't properly execute the query? I think you'll find the variables you are attempting to embed in the query string are not going to be available because they're not in the scope of the function.

Comment: which version of php you are using ?

Comment: don't use mysql any more, use mysqli instead. Anyway which version of php are you using?. mysql_query() needs two parameters, connection and sql string. PLease post any error messages if you have any

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this for the query to work:

```
<?php
------some code here-------
include 'sql.php';
$sql = sql_string1()  ;
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
------some code here------
?>
```

You should also be able to see what the error is if that query failed.

Comment: Yes, you have to somehow provide values for: '$nadpis', '$uvod', '$text', '$datum', '$zobrazeno', '$funiquename','$fileType','$fileSize','$content' inside the function sql_string1();

Hint: (pass it as an array maybe) sql_string1($valuesArray)
Or directly build the SQL in sql.php (without inclosing inside the function)

Comment: for debugging you can add a `var_dump($sql);` after `$sql = sql_string1()  ;` so you can see which command you are acctually sending to the database.